# Simple assignment operation crash app in iOS 9 but not on iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, sqlite

the project has both swift and objective c.

the goal is to pull data from local sqlite DB and assign it

the entities are on objective-c and the call for the db is in swift.

```
    if let item = self.getItemsPrep(){
        ItemsPrep = item
    }
```

> self.getItemsPrep()

pull the data fine, just during assignment it crash on **9.3.1** but not on **11.4** on device

Comment: Is there an error message when it crashes? Maybe some API that doesn't exists on 9.3 but on 10 and/or 11? What's the code of `getItemsPreps()`?

Comment: Why are you referring to `self` explicitly? Isn't the code inside an asynchronous closure? If so, how is `self` reference declared for the closure? Any chance of `[unowned]` ?

Comment: this is the error message`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x70)`   `getItemsPreps()` is a db call and it return one item from a table

Comment: it only have error when assigned to `ItemsPrep` this is how it is initialized 

`@objc class LBuilder: NSObject {
    var ItemsPrep:ItemsPrep
        override init() {
         ItemsPrep = ItemsPrep()
        }`

Comment: You can't have a variable with the same name as a type. It's best practice to use lower camelcase for variable naming, and upper camelcase for type naming. I don't know if your problem is related to the naming, but it doesn't hurt to fix it.

Comment: More code needed please. What is `ItemsPrep` and how is it defined? Could the code which owns `ItemsPrep` be dealloc'd before the block is executed?

Comment: @Marmoy that was when I post it here. It is on the right case

Answer (score 0):

The issue was initializing it before it is really needed

```
@objc class LBuilder: NSObject { 
    var itemsPrep:ItemsPrep? 
        override init() { 
            // itemsPrep = ItemsPrep() 
        }
}
```

So changing the declaration to optional and remove the initialization in `init()` fix the issue on iOS 9